# Outward flux of a vector field through a cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

OK, so I have this homework problem due soon, and I'm not even sure where to start, or how to proceed.

Let $R$ be a region in the plane, and let $P$ be a point at a height $h$ above the plane. Form a cone by drawing lines from $P$ to each point on the boundary of $R$, and define a vector field by $x \Bbb i + y \Bbb j + z \Bbb k$. Denote $D$ as the region in space that is bounded above by the cone, and bounded below by $R$.

With that said, show that the outward flux of the vector field through the boundary of $D$ is $hA$, where $A$ is the area of $R$.

In addition, use the divergence theorem to show that $D$'s volume is $\dfrac {\pi r^2} 3$.

Answer (score 0):

The vector field is conveniently defined by $\mathbf{F} = x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} + z \mathbf{k}$, so that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 3$. (Why?)

Know the statement of the Divergence Theorem. You will see that the right hand side is given by $\iiint \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} dV$. So all that is left to be done is to setup the bounds VERY VERY CAREFULLY from the illustration you are trying to make.